# Best way to store loose hard drives when I don't have an antistatic bag

Tags: hard-drive

I need to store some old 3.5 inch sata hard disks at home, I may get them out occasionally to read the contents, but they are really for long term storage (I understand I should spin them up occasionally to - to make sure they are readable). I would like to know the best way of storing them if I don't have any antistatic bags. I am thinking of wrapping them in greaseproof paper and then putting them in a regular polythene bag (freezer bag style, with a squeeze to close top to stop dust getting in). Would this be a good idea, are there better ideas?

Comment: The best way to store them is with antistatic bags, if you don't have antistatic bags, there are hdd cases that work also. If you care about storing the hdds the correct way use antistatic bags otherwise use your idea but I gurantee you will encounter data loss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a good idea to work out what actually kills drives when doing something like this.

Plastic bags are BAD BAD BAD. Polythene pretty much generates enough static to make your hair stand on end.Grease proof paper has a layer of plastic which might act as polythene does, and paper does pick up static electricity

Just [go get some antistatic bags off amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BSN274) or some local vendor . An alternative would be anti static bubblewrap which some stationary stores sell.

Your data is probably worth more than not taking the effort to do this properly - your idea sounds kinda dangerous